# nginx and proxy_pass handler using ssl on both front-end and backend

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, proxy

I am using an nginx proxy_pass handler to route `http://www.domain.com/api` to `http://api.domain.com` which is fine with http, but when using https, this will put an extra load having to decrypt then reencrypt for backend call, get response decrypt, and renecrypt to return back to client.

Is there anyway around this? Should I be concerned? The backend/api server is on another server. I don't want to be exposed sending data over unencrypted http back and forth to api.

Comment: Is the backend/api server expose to public? If it isn't, I don't see any issue using plain http between front-end and backend, assuming you trust your own network.

Comment: it is exposed to the public because we have several clients (iphone/android/web).

Comment: Is there a private IP / connection that you could use between the 2 servers? If not, I'm afraid either SSL or encrypt/decrypt the API request/response is the only solution.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought. Just curious if I should even be concerned with this. I will check and see if network is private, but I believe access from outside is only on port 443. However, internal network requests should listen on port 80 and 443.